# Rails Action Cable: How to authorize incoming connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am trying to implement authorization on the websocket connection (rails 5.2.1)

Following the [rubyonrails guideline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html), I have created the connection.rb as follows:

**# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private
      def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.encrypted[:user_id])
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, all the websocket connection requests are rejected. (I have figured out that cookies.encrypted[:user_id] is returning nil.)

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2018-10-07 21:33:46 +0300
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2018-10-07 21:33:46 +0300
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_active" = $1 AND "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["is_active", true], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb:12
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2018-10-07 21:33:46 +0300
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2018-10-07 21:33:46 +0300
```

Would you please guide me how I can access current user info within app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get `current_user` from Devise, you need to change your `connection.rb` as follows:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried cookies.signed instead of encrypted but nothing has changed. Also I enabled debugger on the "find_verified_user" method and it seems cookies.signed[:user_id] is nill (although user is authenticated in rails):

(byebug) cookies.signed[:user_id]
nil

Comment: By the way, in order to use Action Cable, I have recently upgraded this app from Rails 4.2.10 to Rails 5.2.1 . I just wanted you to know since this is not a fresh rails 5.2.1 app and I might be missing some other configs which may be required?

Comment: Are you using `devise` as authentication solution or any other gem for this purpose?

Comment: I am using devise

Comment: Well then I think you need to update your `connection.rb` file so it maps with Devise. E.g. `if verified_user = env['warden'].user` in the case of verifying the user. Check the following link to see how to setup ActionCable when using Devise: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/

Comment: Thanks John.. It solved the problem!! :)
Can you pls move the last comment into answer so that I can accept it officially?

Comment: Great! Yep, in a second :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact problem. The way I solved it was by adding a cookie when the user signed in, through `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`. 
The code looks like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
    cookies[:user_id] = current_user.id
  end
end
```

You can get the `SessionsController` from devise by running the code:

`rails generate devise:controllers [scope]`

In my case the scope was users.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6:

```
cookies.encrypted[:user_id]
```

Rails 5:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id]
```